# My SQL error Unknown column 'w' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello I am new in PhP and trying to learn some stuff. 
so I am trying to make a "Simple" registration to start learning the basics as adding and extracting information to the database .
I have the following code but when ever I add information in to the fields and press submit I get this error in return Unknown column 'w' in 'field list'
'w' was in the First Name field

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //Perform Verifications

        $pass  = $_POST['password'];
        $cpass = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

    if($pass == $cpass)
    {
            //carry on
        $name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
        $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $pass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $cpass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `firstname` , `username` , `password` ) VALUES (NULL, `$name`, `$uname` ,`$pass`)") or die(mysql_error());

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Sorry your passwords do not Match.<br />"; 
        exit();
    }

}else{
 $form = <<<EOT
<form action="" method="POST" >
Full Name <input type="text" name="firstname" /> <br />
Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" /> <br />
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
</form>
EOT;

echo $form;
}


?>
```

in the db.php  I just have the code to connect to the database

Comment: Do yourself a favor. If you are learning this now; learn it the right way and start with a [PDO tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338).

Comment: looking it up right now. its completely different of what I have done. cheers for saving me the trouble on learning it the wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `backtick` you have to use quotes in your `values`

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `firstname` , `username` , `password` ) VALUES (NULL, '".$name."', '".$uname."' ,'".$pass."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

If your `id` is auto `incremented field` then remove it from your query

Comment: added the coded you suggested still the same error

Unknown column 'firstname' in 'field list'

Comment: check `firstname` is your column name or not in your database

Comment: yyes you are right, in the database I had it as fullname not firstname